# How to got values from Anyobject when using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

I used AFNetworking in my new personal project with swift. When I post login request to the server, the server will back a response with json while AFNetworking will convert the json to Anyobject. But I got some questions when I try to use the anyobject.

Here is the json data when login succeed:

```
{"code":0,"data":{"id":"1"}}
```

And this is my login code:

```
manager.POST("\(SERVER_HOST)User/login", parameters: params, success: { (operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response:AnyObject!) -> Void in
      var code = response.objectForKey("code") as Int

      if code == 0{
         var data = response.objectForKey("data") as NSDictionary
         var id = data.objectForKey("id")?.integerValue

         self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSucceed", sender: self)
      }

})
```

So my question is :the code can works, but when I use

```
var id = data.objectForKey("id") as Int
```

just like the way I got code value, the app crashed, id got a nil value.Why?

And another question is: what is right way to get the values with a more complicate json string.
Any help will be great appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code crashed when you did:

```
var id = data.objectForKey("id") as Int
```

because the value corresponding to `"id"` is a `String` `"1"` and not an `Int` `1`.  The forced cast `as` crashes if you are wrong about the type.  It is safer to use a conditional cast `as?` and combine that with optional binding:

```
if let code = response["code"] as? Int {
    // if we get here we know "code" is a valid key in the response dictionary
    // and we know we got the type right.  "code" is now an unwrapped `Int` and
    // is ready to use.

    if code == 0 {
        if let data = response["data"] as? NSDictionary {
            // if we get here, we know "data" is a valid key in the response
            // dictionary and we know it holds an NSDictionary.  If it were
            // some other type like `Int` we wouldn't have entered this block

            if let id = data["id"] as? String {
                // if we get here, we know "id" is a valid key, and its type
                // is String.

                // Use "toInt()" to convert the value to an `Int` and use the
                // default value of "0" if the conversion fails for some reason
                let idval = id.toInt() ?? 0
                println("idval = \(idval)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really helpful for your notes in the code!
But how can I know the type of the value? Why code's type is Int and id's type is String?

Comment: Usually you just grab the JSON data and print it to the log before writing the parsing code. Note that the "1" was in quotes but the 0 was not. Also, if you're not sure what type it is, try casting it to both in turn.  `if let id = Data["id"] as? Int { // process Int } else if let id = data["id"] as? String { // process String }`

Comment: Thanks, I will try as what you say

Answer (score 0):

this code maybe work.

```
let json = JSONValue(response)
var code: Int  = json["code"].integer!

if code == 0 {
    if let data = json["data"].object {
       var id = json["data"]["id"].integer!
    }
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSucceed", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: How's `JSONValue` defined?

Answer (score 0):

After some hours googling and searching on github, finally I found a very useful tool parsing json in swift.Here is the link

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

And anyone who saw this question can use AlamoFire instead of AFNetworking in some personal projects.

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Here is another link to working on both AlamoFire and SwiftyJSON

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON